# login/register system getting fatal error php

Tags: php

I have writen a code and there is a error i get could anyone tell me whats wrong please?

error **Fatal error: Call to a member function error() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\loginsistem\index.php on line 6**

but it should say OK! if i m right

init.php:

```
<?php
session_start();

$GLOBALS ['config'] = array(
    'mysql' => array(
        'host' => '127.0.0.1',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'db' => 'lr'
    ),
    'remember' => array(
        'cookie_name' => 'hash',
        'cookie_expiry' => 604800
    ),
    'session' => array(
        'session_name' => 'user'
    )
);

spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
    require_once 'classes/' . $class . '.php';

});

require_once 'functions/sanitize.php';
?>
```

index.php:

```
<?php
require_once 'core/init.php';

$user =DB::getInstance()->get('users', array('username', '=', 'grega'));

if($user->error()) {
    echo 'No user';
} else {
    echo 'OK!';
}

?>
```

DB.php

```
<?php
class DB {
    private static $_instance = null;
    private $_pdo,
            $_query,
            $error = false,
            $_results,
            $count = 0;

    private function __construct() {
        try {
            $this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . Config::get('mysql/host') .';dbname=' . Config::get('mysql/db'), Config::get('mysql/username'), Config::get('mysql/password'));
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static function getInstance() {
        if(!isset(self::$_instance)) {
            self::$_instance = new DB();
        }
        return self::$_instance;
    }

    public function query($sql, $params = array()) {
        $this->_error = false;
        if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)) {
            $x = 1;
            if(count($params)) {
                foreach($params as$param) {
                    $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);
                    $x++;
                }
            }
            if($this->_query->execute()) {
                $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();
            } else {
                $this->_error = true;
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }

    public function action($action, $table, $where = array()) {
        if(count($where) === 3) {
            $operators = array('=', '>', '<', '>=', '<=');

            $field     = '$where[0]';
            $operator  = '$where[1]';
            $value     = '$where[2]';

            if(in_array($operator, $operators)) {
                $sql = "{$action} FROM {$table} WHERE {$field} {$operator} ?";

                if($this->query($sql, array($value))->error()) {
                    return $this;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    public function get($table, $where) {
        return $this->action('SELECT *', $table, $where);
    }
    public function delete($table, $where) {
        return $this->action('DELETE', $table, $where);
    }

    public function error() {
        return $this->_error;
    }

}
```

Comment: Your `action` method isn't always returning `$this`. When it doesn't, the call to `error()` fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably on this part:

```
if($this->query($sql, array($value))->error()) {
    return $this;
}
```

It seems to me that you should modify it with:

```
if( ! $this->query($sql, array($value))->error()) {
    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Split your code like this :

```
// get db instance
$db = DB::getInstance();
// the get function will return $this or false
$users = $db->get('users', array('username', '=', 'grega'));

if($users === false || $db->error()) {
    echo 'No user';
} else {
    echo 'OK!';
}
```

I also saw something weird in your code when you assign values :

```
 $field     = $where[0];
 $operator  = $where[1];
 $value     = $where[2];
```

If you remove ' i think it will work better.

Also you don't need to test error in your function if you test it on your code.

```
if(in_array($operator, $operators)) {
    $sql = "{$action} FROM {$table} WHERE {$field} {$operator} ?";

    $this->query($sql, array($value);
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: but then it always returns me No user .. and i made an user grega in the databse

Comment: I see, there's also a problem when you assign values.

Comment: but when i use this code i get No user everytime if i write in a valid user thats in database or if i dont its No user everytime

Comment: I simplified the return part